# How to share memory with multi actor in Ray

Tags: parallel-processing, shared-memory, actor, multiprocess, ray

I'm working on linux,using python 3.8.5,here is my codes:

```
oaglog.logger.info("begin to read graph。。。")
graph = renamed_load(open(os.path.join(ABSULUTE_DIR + args.data_dir, 'graph%s.pk' % args.domain), 'rb'))
oaglog.logger.info("read graph successed。")

ray_graph = ray.put(graph)

@ray.remote
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.n = 0
        self.a = a
    def increment(self):
        self.n += 1

    def read(self,b,m_graph):
        print("a")
        self.increment()
        print(id(m_graph))
        del m_graph
        return self.n * b

counters = [Counter.remote(a=0) for i in range(8)]
futures = [c.read.remote(2, ray_graph) for c in counters]

print('******************************')
print(ray.get(futures))
```

Because the graph is huge(about 9Gb),so I want to put it into shared memory, I tried ray.put(), but it failed, the graph was copied 8 times, I was wondering whether Ray offers an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

The graph is being copied because it's an arbitrary python object and is copied because each of your actors may try to modify their copy of it.

Ray is able to avoid copying python objects for certain types of [objects which can be loaded in a read-only way](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serialization.html#numpy-arrays).

If you can represent your graph as a numpy array, it will automatically be loaded as a read-only numpy array in each of your actors and won't be copied.

You could also implement out-of-band pickle deserialization for your object yourself, [which is a bit more tricky](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/).